# Paypal Sandbox App login error

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I've a problem with my sandbox app. I integrated the script given for the paypal checkout express payment in my web app. This the script :

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script>
    var total = 0;
    $.getJSON("/Home/getTotal", function (result) {
        total = result;
    });
    // Render the PayPal 
    paypal.Button.render({

        // Set your environment

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Specify the style of the button

        style: {
            label: 'buynow',
            fundingicons: true, // optional
            branding: true // optional
        },

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

        client: {
            sandbox: 'AT9iydEDhcqfM_dhU8MR0lvkFgZBjD1oXQVrG-CR9CyK_vd-aXpNzEnyVV7um_hAPrkqQX8JhtjGCbBt'
        },

        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

        payment: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: total, currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
                window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

This code displays a paypal button. When I click on the button, it shows me a login page to proceed to the payement. The problem is : I can't login on this page with a paypal account that I have. I read somewhere that only the sandbox's test accounts can be used to login on this page, but I want to let everyone who has a paypal account login in this page. What should I do ? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: did you create a PayPal app like the code says to do?

Comment: Yes, I've created 2 sandbox app

Comment: If you want to let everybody to login then you should use a production account and not a sandbox

Comment: It's what I just found out, where can I get the production code ? I just changed my paypal plan to business plan

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution : if you want to let everybody login into your payment's page, you've to pass to production mode.